# Firebase google signin emailVerified always true

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to implement a sign in form using firebase web and vue.js. The problem is that I want to send an email to verify the email address but the signin user has the emailVerified key always in true by default. Does somebody knows if there is any way to set it to false?

[image]

[image]

Comment: On Stack Overflow, don't show pictures of code and text.  Copy the code into the question and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: ok, good to know it. But actually that code works perfect. I just wanted to show my current process for making a clear picture.

Comment: I'm suggesting that you should edit the question to remove the pictures and instead copy the code into it. It doesn't matter if the code works or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't set that flag.  It's managed by Firebase Auth.  My guess for the reason that it's always set true by default (for Google auth, as you imply here) is that Google manages the email verification scheme for their own accounts.  You can be sure that, if you get an email address for a Google account, the email does in fact work and belong to the user.

Answer (score 2):

As i can see that you are using google login , So if someone logins through google the email is already verified . If you want to send verification mail use email/password signin .